# Suppose that $f'(x)g(x)=f(x)g'(x)$ and $g(x)\ne 0$ on (a,b). How are $f$ and $g$ related?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Suppose that $f'(x)g(x)=f(x)g'(x)$ and $g(x)\ne 0$ on (a,b).

How are $f$ and $g$ related?

---

I posted this earlier and accidentally deleted it.

But thus far, I have:

Let $$h(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$

Then
$$h'(x)=\frac{f'(x)g(x)-f(x)g'(x)}{(g(x))^2}$$

Since $f'(x)g(x)=f(x)g'(x)$, I propose we replace $f(x)g'(x)$ in $h'(x)$ and we get

$$h'(x)=\frac{f'(x)g(x)-f'(x)g(x)}{(g(x))^2}$$
$$=\frac{0}{(g(x))^2}$$

---

Is it enough, then, to say that $f$ and $g$ are constants on $(a,b)$?

Comment: I don't know if it leads to a solution, but there's an interesting consequence: If $f'(x)g(x)=f(x)g'(x)$ for all $x\in(a,b)$, then this relation holds upon differentiation as well and this simplifies to $f''(x)g(x)=f(x)g''(x)$. Taking the $n$th derivative, one more generally obtains $f^{(n)}(x)g(x)=f(x)g^{(n)}(x)$.

Comment: You know that $h$ is constant, you do not know that $f$ and $g$ are constants. But $h$ being constant implies a relationship between the two functions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember your definition of h. You have just managed to prove that:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$$
This implies:
$$f(x) = Cg(x)$$
Where C is any constant.

Answer (score 2):

In your quotient rule, it must be $(-)$. Now, using the assumption, $h^\prime(x)=0$ on $(a,b)$. What can you conclude about $h$ on $(a,b)$?

Comment: Yes, I fixed the quotient rule. Not sure what I was thinking.
So, with $h'(x)=0$ we can conclude that $h(x)$ is some constant on $(a,b)$ and thus both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are constants? Is that enough?

Comment: @Bellatrix1106 - you keep asking the same question over and over again - if $f/g$ is constant does that mean $f$ and $g$ are constant? NO IT DOESN'T. $g$ can be any function (almost; it still must be differentiable and nonzero everywhere), and $f$ is any CONSTANT multiple of $g$. Example: $g(x) = x^2 + \cos x$ and $f(x) = - 3x^2-3\cos x$. (On some interval where $g \ne 0$ everywhere.)