# If $g(x)f'(x) = f(x)g'(x)$ show there is some $c$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=cg(x) \forall x$ in $\mathbb{R}$. (Fitzpatrick 4.3, 15)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

I am working through an exercise in the Fitzpatrick Advanced Calculus book for some practice, section 4.3 exercise 15:

> Let $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable and suppose $g(x)f'(x) = f(x)g'(x)$ for all $x$.
>
> If $g(x) \ne 0$ show there is some $c$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=cg(x)$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

**Attempt**

Let $h(x)=g(x)f(x)$, so $h'(x)=f'(x)g(x)+g'(x)f(x)$. Then  by hypothesis, $h'(x)=f'(x)g(x)+g'(x)f(x)=2f'(x)g(x)=2g'(x)f(x)$. So $\frac{2}{2}=\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$. Now obviously we are trying to show that $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=c$.  So by setting $c=2/2 = 1$ it seems like we have proven the desired result.

Is this correct? Seems too simple.

Comment: Why does $\frac{2}{2}=\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$?

Comment: A proper solution is e.g. here: [Suppose that $f'(x)g(x)=f(x)g'(x)$ and $g(x)\ne 0$ on (a,b). How are $f$ and $g$ related?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2014670/suppose-that-fxgx-fxgx-and-gx-ne-0-on-a-b-how-are-f-and-g)

Comment: Consider $x^2$ and $|x|x$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian. Note g$\ne0$ is a strong assumption.

Comment: It actually *is* part of the question - see above.

Comment: Ah, then your method is fine.

Comment: $h'(x)=f'(x)g(x)+g'(x)f(x)=2f'(x)g(x)=2g'(x)f(x)$ does not implies that $\frac{2}{2}=\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$. You should use the quotient rule.

Comment: If $c=1$, then we must have $f(x)=g(x)$. But obviously, we have $g(x)f'(x)=f(x)g'(x)$  when $f(x)=cg(x)$, where $c$ can be any real number.

Comment: I'm sorry @CYAries I don't quite follow.  Why is quotient rule necessary here?  It seems to me like only basic algebra

Comment: Both the answers below are correct. Your proof is incorrect as your expression of $h'(x)$ does not imply that $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone will hopefully comment on your attempt but the result follows from the fact that the equation
$$
g(x)f'(x)=f(x)g'(x)
$$
together with the assumption $g\neq 0$ implies that
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)=0
$$
whence
$$
\frac{f}{g}=c
$$
for some $c$.

Comment: so product rule not necessary at all here right?

Comment: @guimption: you just need the quotient rule. Upon using the hypothesis, the numerator of the quotient rule turns out to be $0$.

Comment: Quotient rule is product rule plus chain rule

Answer (score 1):

The issues with our OP guimption's proposed solution are adequately addressed in the comments.  Therefore I cut to the chase:

Given that

$g(x) \ne 0, \forall x \in \Bbb R, \tag 1$

the function

$\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} \tag 2$

is well-defined for all $x \in \Bbb R$; furthermore,

$\left ( \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} \right )' = \dfrac{f'(x)g(x) - f(x)g'(x)}{(g(x))^2} = 0, \tag 3$

since

$f'(x)g(x) - f(x)g'(x) = 0, \; \forall x \in \Bbb R; \tag 4$

thus $f(x) / g(x)$ is constant; that is,

$\exists c \in \Bbb R, \; \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}  = c, \forall x \in \Bbb R; \tag 5$

it follows then that

$f(x) = cg(x), \; \forall x \in \Bbb R. \tag 6$

Comment: it would help me to know what tools you are using to prove each part.  In step $(5)$, I understand that there exists an $x_0$ in the domain such that $\frac{f(x_0)}{g(x_0)}=c$, but why can we say that it is true for all $x$?  Is that the mean value theorem?

Comment: @guimption:  if I don't answer by tomorrow, ask me again.  Falling asleep now . . .

Comment: @guimption:  I think the logical tools behind most of my steps are pretty self-evident if not downright trivial, except perhaps for the transition from (3) to (5).  Here the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus comes into play, not the Mean Value Theorem.  The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus asserts that $F(b) - F(a) = \int_a^b F'(s) \; ds$, with $F'(x) = 0$ we find $F(b) = F(a)$ for all $b$, so $F(x)$ is constant.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus.

Comment: @guimption:  the fact that $F'(x) = 0$ implies $F(x)$ is constant is so universally used that I didn't feel it was necessary to justify it.  Cheers!

Comment: @guimption:  I hope these remarks of mine clarify for you.  If not, feel free to ask more questions.  Cheers!

Comment: @guimption:  I guess it can also be done with the Mean Value Theorem, since if $F(b) \ne F(a)$ there is some $c \in (a, b)$ with $F'(c) \ne 0$, so if $F'(x) = 0$ everywhere on $[a, b]$, $F(b) = F(a)$.